# Avoid any change on master, when using SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm currently participating in an open source project, and we are using git to manage quite a number of branches, pull requests, etc.

Although I really like the git command line, I consider to use SourceTree. However, since it is a graphical user interface, I fear, that I click somewhere by mistake and push some changes to master.

Can I tell SourceTree to not touch master? I want neither commits, nor rebases, etc. to manipulate the master branch in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `master` as a [Protected Branch](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/). 
Additionally, as a rule, you can avoid local checking out of any branch you are not working on. Keep your local branches clean, *check out* only what you need.

[image: A clean local repo]

Comment: "Protected branches" require the project to be hosted on Github - luckily the case for my project.

Comment: @slartidan GitHub FTW! :)

Answer (score 0):

On SourceTree you can choose a branch by double-clicking on it. From there on your commits are applicable to that branch and if you do not choose the master branch, you have nothing to fear about clicking. Also, if you click on Commit, it will not automatically commit your changes. A panel will be shown where you can view what is being committed and check the files to commit, write a commit messages, etc. At this panel, by clicking on the Commit button, you are saving your commit locally on your machine.

By clicking on Push a panel is shown where you can view what is being pushed. If you do not like it, you can cancel it. Otherwise you can confirm your intention.

If you have accidentally committed something wrong, but did not push it yet, you can right-click on the commit and choose Strip from here.

So, you will not accidentally commit anything on master. However, when you finish your branch, you might need to merge that into master, which can be done by Git/HG flow. If you want to partially put your changes to master without closing your branch, you can double-click on master, right-click on your branch and choose to merge.

The accidents you are afraid of are practically impossible.

Comment: I'm rebasing branches, by checking out the branch, right clicking on "Rebase..." and accepting. If I, by mistake, would not "rebase my changes on master" but "rebase master on my changes", I would receive some emails of my collegues :)

Comment: @slartidan all this happens under the hood correctly using SourceTree. I think you should create a very simple versioned project with separate branches and use SourceTree with that to play before using it on your main project. You will see that double-clicking on a branch will highlight that branch and you will see where you are. You will be able to do anythiing with this test project and test all the scenarios you are afraid of. You will see whether your concerns are solved by the tool or not. If yes, then you can use it and you will already have experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not checkout `origin/master`, with tracking enabled.
2. Do not configure any local branch to track `origin/master`.
3. Do not create local branches, that are called `master` (If you pushed that branch, SourceTree would automatically match names).

Still it would be technically possible to modify remote master, but it requires you to explicitly specify it (for example "Remotes/origin/master, rightclick, delete" is still possible, but unlikely to happen unintentionally).